# Minimax estimator of $\sigma^2$

Tags: statistics

Let $X_1,...,X_n$~$N(\mu,\sigma^2)$ and let $\theta=(\mu,\sigma^2)^T$ and $\mu$ is known.
We would like to find the minimax estimator of $\sigma^2$ among the decisions $D_0$,

$D_0=\{\delta_0:\delta_c(x)=c\Sigma^n_{i=1} (x_i - \bar x)^2,c>0\}$

And we define the loss function,

$L(\theta,a)=(a/\sigma^2 - 1 ) ^2,~a \in D_0$

We would like to find the one which minimizes the maximum risk:

$\delta^{minimax(D_0)} = arg min_{\delta \in D_0}max_\theta R(\theta,\delta)$

I first computed $R(\theta,\delta)=E(cU_n-1)^2=E(c^2U_n^2-2cU_n+1)=c^2n^2-2cn-c^2+2c+1$

where

$U_n=(\Sigma^n _{i=1} (X_i-\bar X)/\sigma^2 -1) $ ~ $\chi^2(n-1)$

and found out that $R(\theta,\delta_c)$ is a function of c and it doesn't depend on $\theta$.

But I don't know what to do next and stuck on this step.
Can anyone help me solve this problem?

Comment: Have you presented the problem correctly? Looks to me your $\delta_c$ is missing a square. You say $\mu$ is known and still consider an estimator like $\sum (X_i-\overline X)^2$.

Comment: I edited $\delta_c$. thanks! What do you mean by still considering estimator like $\Sigma(X_i-\bar X)^2$?

Comment: $\sum (X_i-\overline X)^2$ perhaps makes more sense as an estimator of $\sigma^2$ when $\mu$ is unknown, in which case we estimate $\mu$ by $\overline X$.